# condition on the dimensions of a matrix for its inverse to exist

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, what condition on the dimensions $m$ and $n$ is necessary for the quantity $(A^t\times A)^{-1}$ to exist? Please kindly provide your explanation.

Many thanks!

Comment: That inverse matrix exists iff $A$ is injective. But what have you been able to do yourself? I don't want to give a full answer unless you elaborate on what you understand and don't understand.

Comment: Short answer: $m \ge n$ is necessary (but not sufficient).

Comment: @p.s.Can you briefly explain why m has to be >= n? Thanks!

Comment: If $m < n$, then $A^T A$ will be [rank deficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)). (It's a $n \times n$ matrix, but its rank its at most $m$, so it can't be invertible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a real matrix of any size.
(This also works with complex matrices if transpose is replaced with conjugate transpose. The proof is the same.)
Then $A^TA$ is a bijection (has an inverse) if and only if $A$ is an injection.

Suppose $A$ is an injection.
If $A^TAx=0$ for some $x$, then
$$
0
=
x^T0
=
x^TA^TAx
=
(Ax)^T(Ax)
=
|Ax|^2
$$
and so $Ax=0$.
By injectivity of $A$ this implies $x=0$.
Therefore $A^TA$ is injective.
But $A^TA$ is a square matrix, so injectivity implies bijectivity.

Suppose $A$ is not injective.
Then there is an $x\neq0$ so that $Ax=0$.
But then also $A^TAx=A^T0=0$, so $A^TA$ is not injective and thus not bijective.

Comment: I don' t quite understand why you can write (Ax)T(Ax)=|Ax|2, how can you tell Ax is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: @SamuelSong, for any vector $y$ we have $y^Ty=y\cdot y=|y|^2$. I used this for $y=Ax$.

Comment: when you say a matrix is injective, are you saying it is non-surjective?

Comment: No. I'm using the usual definition of injectivity. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

Comment: I see there is an answer to my question which state that "m≥n is necessary (but not sufficient)" do you have any comment on it?

Comment: @SamuelSong, yes. The matrix $A$ can only be injective if $m\geq n$. The comment is correct. Check your theorems related to dimension and rank.

Comment: is that true that rank(AT*A) must equal to n (if AT*A is a n*n square matrix) in order to become invertible?

Comment: @SamuelSong, yes. If you have a book or course material about linear algebra, it will explain why. It's not a good idea to have a lengthy discussion in the comments. If you need something else explained, ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For the inverse of any matrix to exist is that the matrix must be square. As long as [A(Transpose)*A] is a matrix of m x n dimensions where m = n than an inverse can exist.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not all square matrices have inverses. The matrix $A^TA$ is always a square, but not always invertible.

Comment: Is there any way for us to restrict m and n in order to let all square matrix ATA invertible?

Comment: @SamuelSong, no. You will always have the zero matrix, no matter what.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta Sorry but I don't quite understand. For example a matrix [1,2;3,4;5,6] its transpose times itself should be a 3*3 matrix with no zero, isn't it?

Comment: @SamuelSong, yes, but if $A=0$ then $A^TA=0$. Thus you can't expect $A^TA$ to be invertible for _all_ $A$.

Comment: $A^T\times A$ is always an $n\times n$ matrix, if $A$ is $m\times n$. But if $m<n$ it will _never_ be invertible (because of rank at most$~m$).

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has size $m\times n$ then $A^T\cdot A$ has size $n\times n$ and rank at most $\min(m,n)$. Since being invertible means having rank$~n$, a necessary condition for invertibility is $n=\min(m,n)$ or equivalently $m\geq n$. This condition is not sufficient. One has $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}\rk(A^T\cdot A)\leq\rk A=\rk(A^T)$, so it is also necessary that $A$ has (full column) rank$~n$, which means it (or the associated linear map) is injective.

Over arbitrary fields that condition is still not sufficient, since even if $A$ is injective one has  $\dim(\ker(A^T\cdot A))=\dim(\operatorname{Im}(A)\cap\ker(A^T))$ and that intersection might be nonzero making $A^T\cdot A$ non-invertible. However when the field is $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$, the standard bilinear form $x^T y$ is positive definite, and $\ker(A^T)$ is the orthogonal complement for that form of $\operatorname{Im}(A)$, which forces the intersection to be zero. So if the base field is $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$, then the condition $\rk(A)=n$ (which implies $m\geq n$) is not only necessary but also sufficient for $A^T\cdot A$ to be invertible.